# Jquery add using append and remove using .remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, webrtc, removechild

I'm trying to make two buttons that acts as remove and add function first I have this:

HTML

```
<video id="localVideo" style="background-color:black"></video>
<div id="remoteVideos"></div>
```

Buttons

```
<button id="BtnOn">On</button>
<button id="BtnOff">Off</button>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            //$("#BtnOn").click(function() {
             //   $('#A').append("<div id='localVideo'>");
             //   $('#A').append("<div id='remoteVideos'>");            
        //});

            $("#BtnOff").click(function() {
                $("#localVideo").remove();
        $("#remoteVideos").remove();
        });    
            });
```

What I'm trying to do is remove the 2 div's and have the ability to return them, with the condition that you can only add them if they are missing and remove them if they are present, therefore limiting them to 1 add and 1 remove. How can I accomplish this?Any help suggestion is appreciated

Comment: There's only one `div` here - do you mean the `video` as well?

Comment: yes sir, the remove button is working, my only problem is how to limit it and the functionality of the add button @dsaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the `#localVideo` element exists. Also, if they are the only elements in the `#A` element, you can remove them by calling `$('#A').empty();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#BtnOn').click(function() {
        if ($('#localVideo').length == 0) {
            $('#A').append('<video id="localVideo" style="background-color:black"></video><div id="remoteVideos"></div>');
        }
    });

    $('#BtnOff').click(function() {
        if ($('#localVideo').length > 0) {
            $("#localVideo").remove();
            $("#remoteVideos").remove();
        }
    });    
});
```

You could also consider hiding and showing the video elements, rather than adding and removing them.

Comment: tnx mate, I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.append()` and `.remove()`, you can change the CSS `display` property to `none` or `initial`, depending on whether you want the thing to be shown or not.

This way, you can then add an if statement like so:

```
$("#BtnOff").click(function() {
    if('#localvideo').css('display') == 'none'){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        $('#localVideo').css('display','none');
        $('#remoteVideos').css('display','none');
    }
});
```